# postgresql select lines in json array with LIKE operator

Tags: json, postgresql

I have one table **user** with one JSON field **user_data**.
Example these 3 lines :

```
{"name": "John", domain_names: ['john.com', 'lennon.com', 'john.fr']}
{"name": "Foo", domain_names: ['foo.com', 'bar.fr', 'bar.com']}
{"name": "Tirion", domain_names: ['tirion.co.uk']}
```

I want to get JSON lines with one or more **.com** domaine name (The first two lines).
I tried this :

```
SELECT user_data 
FROM user 
WHERE json_array_elements(user_data)->>'domain_names' LIKE '%.com';
```

but it doesn't work...
Do you know a way to get lines with **.com** domain ?

Comment: This would be extremely simple if you used a normalized data model.

Comment: Yes but original data are more complicated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_data
FROM "user" u
WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(u.user_data->'domain_names') x(dom)
          WHERE dom LIKE '%.com');
```

By the way, you should avoid naming tables like reserved words (in that case `user`).